# Monitor all JavaScript events in the browser console

Tags: javascript, events

Is it possible to listen to all javascript events?

I'm trying to guess if there's an event triggered after the DOM is modified by an AJAX request.

Comment: Look under Mutation here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Common.2FW3C_events are these the events you're after?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to intercept onreadystatechange event on all XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 114, accepted):

With [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#monitorEvents.28object.5B.2C_types.5D.29) or [web inspector](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html) you can use `monitorEvents`:

```
monitorEvents(myDomElem);
```

This prints all events emitted by `myDomElem` to the console.  Use `unmonitorEvents` to stop monitoring events.

If you're interested in getting events after the DOM has been manipulated, take a look at [Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents).

**Edit**:

As far as I know, there is no easy way to intercept all `onreadystatechange` events from all XMLHttpRequest.  The only work-around I can think of is to override the native XMLHttpRequest object with you own implementation.  For example:

```
(function() { // Overriding XMLHttpRequest
    var oldXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;

    function newXHR() {
        var realXHR = new oldXHR();

        realXHR.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() { 
            console.log("an ajax request was made") 
        }, false);

        return realXHR;
    }

    window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR;
})();
```

Needless to say this is extremely hacky and generally ill-advised.

Comment: yes, http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/ just hooks jQuery's XHR wrapper, so no real JS event is captured. However this hack should do the trick :)

Comment: "generally ill-advised" - why?

Comment: Update: `monitorEvents` works perfectly fine in Chrome just as well.

Comment: (it fires _tons_ of `mousemove` events, however)

Comment: @JanDvorak It's generally ill-advised because it make the browser environment ever more unpredictable.  For example, imagine if one day XMLHttpRequest constructors start allowing parameters?  The implementation I provided above ignores all constructor parameter, which mean it could silently break some time in the future.  And when it does, could lead to a number of confusing and frustrating bugs.  This blog post mentions other reasons why it's a bad idea: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

Comment: Is there some way to show events which are fired before I'm able to enter a command into the console (automatically fired on page reload) in Chrome. Firefox seems to have a `persist` argument (not tried).

Comment: It should be noted that `monitorEvents` does not respond to custom events, and only responds to the following standard events:
mousedown, mouseup, click, dblclick, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, mousewheel, key, keydown, keyup, keypress, textInput touchstart, touchmove, touchend, touchcancel, resize, scroll, zoom, focus, blur, select, change, submit, reset, load, unload, abort, error, select, change, submit, reset, focus, blur, resize, scroll, search, devicemotion, and deviceorientation. (via the monitorEvents source,  http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/chrome-developer-tools-monitorevents)

Comment: `monitorEvents` is available in Safari 9 too

Answer (score 21):

To piggy back off Xavi's answer of `monitorEvents(myDomElem)`, if you wanted everything but the mouse events, you could then enter `unmonitorEvents(myDomElem, 'mouse')`.

http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/chrome-developer-tools-monitorevents has a good article in regards to using chrome monitor events.