# Debugging event handlers added to an element via jQuery

Tags: jquery, iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I am trying to debug some complex code in which some UI gets created in an iPhone phonegap application.

The problem is that it would seem that when I press the element the event handlers (that are supposedly) attached to its `touchstart` event don't fire.

Its either that for some reasons those events are not really attached, or the click gets blocked before reaching them somehow...

I am trying to debug this situation and was wondering:

1. Given a jQuery object, is the a way to list the event handlers attached to it (via jQuery) for debugging purposes?
2. Is there an easy way to override `.on` and have it `console.log` its parameters
3. any other ideas on how I should approach such a problem

**UPDATE**: 
After validating that indeed the element has the `touchstart` handler and it is not being called I have discovered that if I am adding click or `mousedown` event handlers they do get called.

I suspect this is caused partly by jQuery mobile but I am not sure how or why and why it effects only part of my controls (those are not JQM controls...).

Comment: You can get all the event handlers using `$("#id").data("events");`

Comment: @thomas, this was a very good pointer. It allowed me to validate that an event handler for the `touchstart` event is indeed attached to my element. however still, it does not get called when I press the element on the screen of the device. any ideas on where I should go to now ?

Comment: @thomas, do you know if this can be expressed as a selector ? i.e. select elements that have events ?

Comment: Didn't know it but after a 10 second search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector

Answer (score 0):

[This Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi) lists attached JQuery Events.

Comment: this might be helpful in other scenarios. however it does not help me As my debugging is done via the phonegap remote debug console (winere).

Answer (score 0):

[How do you log all events fired by an element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439570/how-do-you-log-all-events-fired-by-an-element-in-jquery/10995631#10995631)

```
function getEventsList($obj) {
    var ev = new Array(),
        $events = $obj.data('events');
    for(var i in $events) {
        ev.push(i);
    }
    return ev.join(' ');
}

$obj.on(getEventsList($obj), function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

I used this to find out what exact custom event was bound to an element by a jquery plugin. It gets all the attached events and calls a console.log for the event when it is fired.