# jQuery log event bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

Let's imagine I have the following line of code in two different JS files:

```
$("select#selectorId").change(function() { alert("fake function"); });
```

Every time I bind the function to the change event of that select control I want to be able to log on the console what function is the control receiving and to what event is it being bound to.

Anyone knows if this is possible (almost everything is right?) and how to do it?

Comment: This might provide the solution: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2390-Tracing-Event-Binding-And-Event-Triggering-In-jQuery.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10995631/294076

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select#selectorId").on('change',function() { alert("fake function"); });
```

Comment: .live is deprecated since 1.7.0 (I believe). use .on instead