# User Activity Tracking using javascript library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, logging

Is it possible to track every action of a user on a webpage and creating log of it? The idea is to transfer log of user actions to server via AJAX and saving it. On each event for each element I can write code/logic to write some log in console, but I was wondering if there is any library/shortcut available which can log all actions on webpage at client side including events and actions such as copy, paste, click, double click, selection etc. with their element reference.

Comment: So basically you want to re-create Google Analytics?

Comment: Just logging as of now :) creating analytical reports are too far to think.

Comment: I found something here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7439584/1356109 but its for single element. I'm looking for some dynamic solution. I guess $( "*" ) should work.

Comment: You might find this [blog post](https://www.techighness.com/post/javascript-track-user-activity-on-webpage-with-custom-script/) useful. It shares custom JavaScript code to track user activity on a webpage.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use ready-made solutions:

- http://www.google.com/analytics/
- http://www.clicktale.com/
- https://segment.io/
- http://www.extrawatch.com/
- http://mouseflow.com/
- https://www.seevolution.com/
- http://clicky.com/

You can do amazing stuff with Google Analytics and its Event Tracker:

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide
- http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2287906/10-Google-Analytics-Custom-Events-That-Track-the-Untrackable

If you're looking for a custom-made solution, you can try the following one with PHP and JavaScript:

- http://css-tricks.com/tracking-clicks-building-a-clickmap-with-php-and-jquery/

Keep in mind that using third-party solutions is better performance-wise. Writing the coordinates of the mouse movements in a database in real time, needs a lot of resources.

Comment: A few words to describe what each of these links are would be very helpful.

Answer (score 16):

Personally I **hate** 3rd party like **google analytics** and similar company. Because I dont want to share my web analytics with them. Anyway there is a very very **lightweight** (about 5KB minified) and **easily extendable** javascript library.

Here is git **repo**: https://github.com/greenstick/interactor
and you can see a **preview** of it: http://greenstick.github.io/interactor/

**What Data is Provided?**

General Data:

- Which page is loaded
- When the user loaded the page
- When the user left the page
- The URL of the loaded page
- The previous page location
- The title of the page
- The language settings of the user
- The user's platform
- The port used to access the web server
- The inner and outer width and height of the web browser

Interaction / Conversion Data:

- The interaction type (i.e. general interaction or conversion)
- The time of the interaction
- The event that triggered interaction
- The target HTML element tag
- The target HTML element classes
- The target HTML element content (i.e. text, etc.)
- The cursor position relative to client
- The cursor position relative to screen

Example:

```
var elementsToTrack = [
{
    element: "element1",
    events : ["mouseup", "touchend"]
}, 
{
    element: "element2",
    events : ["mouseup"]
},
{ 
    element: "element3",
    events : ["mouseup"]
}
];

for (var i = 0; i < elementsToTrack.length; i++) {
var e = elementsToTrack[i];
new Interactor({
    interactionElement  : e.element,
    interactionEvents   : e.events
});
}
```

I Hope this information will be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that this kind of javascript library exist, you could easily build one with jquery, just listen to all the event (`blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup  mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error`)

and than send them to the server side using [web sockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

Answer (score 4):

Have you look at [Google Analytic Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)?

You need to embed the tracking function within your javascript but it is very convenience to use.

```
// Google API
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)

// Example
_trackEvent('checkout' 'remove-item' 'poodle skirt')
```

---

**Update: 2017**
[New Analytics Api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

```
// Api
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);

// Example remove product id#27
ga('send', 'event', 'ecart', 'remove-item', 'poodle skirt', 27);
   // OR
ga('send', {
      hitType: 'event',
      eventCategory: 'ecart',
      eventAction: 'remove-item',
      eventLabel: 'poodle skirt'
   });
```