# Jquery debug ajax requests remote submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to be able to submit a debug report back to the server if the user encounters any issues (*maybe they will click on a button or something*).

One approach I can envision for this is just log all the ajax calls manually into an array, along with all the responses, used variables etc, and then submit that variable on the submission of debug report by the end user.

Is there an automated process to compile all the runtime vars, all of the ajax requests + response. So that the debug team has a starting point to replicate the issue?

Comment: There are user activity logging software packages out there that can help with this type of thing:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713415/user-activity-tracking-or-logging-with-javascript

Comment: Although similar, That is a different thing, mostly it will include click heatmaps and user's activity, I am more interested on the debugging part & environment vars.