# How to create a user/event tracking tool, backed by Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, tracking

are there any good references to start looking into building a simple but efficient tracking/event tool? Super simple version of a tool like Google Analytics. I am assuming this consist of two separate applications. One for the front-end which gets embedded into the client's website, and a back-end API to handle the events, queue, etc.

Preferred tools for the back-end for me is Rails.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be reinventing the wheel, but you'll need a javascript library to track the user and a rails API. Pretty much what you seem to know you need.

Here's the documentation on building a rails API: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html

Refer to the top answer here for the javascript module: [User Activity Tracking or Logging with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713415/user-activity-tracking-or-logging-with-javascript)