# User events and data in Express backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, backend

I am making an analytics API which needs the given fields ,

user's browser, user's IP,

user events like button clicks, page loads, etc.

The first two can be achieved from request headers, (please correct me if i am wrong) but i cant get an idea how to achieve the third one.

Comment: You need client side code that catches those events and then sends it to the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to the two first, task. I agree that they can be achieved this way.

Answering to your question, and following the NullDev comment you should use some client side script that track that behaviour and send it back to the server.

Someone asked this before, and should be useful for your case:

[User Activity Tracking using javascript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713415/user-activity-tracking-using-javascript-library)

I hope this helps to solve your problem, greetings.