# barcode scanner produces a "keypress" event only when the user is on an input box. What event to listen to when user is not on an input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, barcode, dom-events

*Context*:

I'm working on a web application that uses a barcode scanner device. Users scan barcodes, I redirect them to the appropriated page.

*Problem*:

The scan device I'm using triggers "keypress" events ONLY when the user is in a input box element

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    // do something with the event
}
```

I would like to be able to scan barcodes from ANYWHERE in my application (even when I'm not in an input box). (Yes I know that the code above will fire for every character, I have a timer based algorithm to know if it's a barcode reader or a person typing.).

*So far* :

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290898/detect-when-input-box-filled-by-keyboard-and-when-by-barcode-scanner), so I tried to replace the accepted solution's selector with a more general selector (window or document) without luck. Is there other events more appropriated for this task? I'm open to suggestions on doing it another way.

*--EDIT--* :

After more research I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981445/javascript-catch-input-when-no-input-has-focus). The problem is that my view might not have any input. Just plain text

Thank you

Comment: You could try `document.addEventListener`, but your existing code should also work.

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633537/javascript-how-to-read-a-hand-held-barcode-scanner-best) and see if it can offer you any assistance. It looks like you need to listen for a couple of events `keydown` and `textInput`

Comment: @AdamH Thank you for the response. I don't think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290898/detect-when-input-box-filled-by-keyboard-and-when-by-barcode-scanner/15354814#15354814) answer will work as `$(document).on({keyup: ...` is not picking up the scanner's output. 
I put break points on that part and it's picking up the keyboard fine but not the scanner (when you are not in a input box).

Comment: What about the possible solutions in the question I linked? sounds like they were having the exact same issue that you were. There are a few possible solutions in that thread.

Comment: @AdamH I went through the thread. Almost all possible solutions. But they are all assuming that there is a input box in the view. They are basically focusing the input and then reading the keypress event. But my view might not have input boxes and I wrote in my edit. 

I think it is currently impossible (from a javascript point of view) to get the input from a barcode scanner device if there is no input in your page you can focus to.

Comment: @ObjectOrientedPirate read this thread again, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633537/javascript-how-to-read-a-hand-held-barcode-scanner-best, the top answers are not suggesting you attach to an input. They are all attaching to either window or document and listening for either `textInput` or `keydown`

Comment: @AdamH events ["keydown", "keyup", "keypress"] in the document are triggered (even if there is no input box). On a debugging point of view, I see that keys from keyboard trigger the above events no matter what. Sadly the barcode reader only trigger the above event if the user is focused on an input box. 

I gave a shot to "textInput" event but it's not working either. If I have time, I'll make a code snippet so we can both agree on the playground and test the same things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is for people that may want to know the answer:

For some reason, the following code works with all the scanner I've tested:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    // your handler here
}, true)
```

Note that the boolean true can also be false. Why it didn't work for "window.addEventListener" nor for "document.addEventListener"? I don't know.