# Always have the cursor in the only input field

Tags: php, input, scope

I have a simple form : 1 field that takes input from a bar-code reader.
With some manipulation, a list of records is displayed with a slider for seeing all the records if required.
When the user clicks on the slider (or anywhere out of the single input field) the bar-code reader input is not placed as a value of the field of the form... which is a normal behavior.

Is it possible to always have the cursor placed in the input field ?

Thanks

Comment: PHP runs on the server, it has nothing to do with interactions on the client. This needs to be done in JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript catch input when no input has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981445/javascript-catch-input-when-no-input-has-focus)

Comment: YES!!! Wonderful. It was my first question... I should have ask before instead of pulling my hairs off!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.