# How do I detect the DOM events being fired from a website?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, event-listener

Some sites signal content change DOM events, such as:

- `pjax:end` on document used by many pjax-based sites e.g. GitHub;
- `message` on window used by e.g. Google search in Chrome browser;
- `yt-navigate-finish` used by Youtube

Currently, I'm using `console.table(listAllEventListeners());` to list all the event listeners on a webpage, but what I want is to log to the console whenever one of these events is fired.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hello there is a feature in chrome. Look this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439570/how-do-you-log-all-events-fired-by-an-element-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439570/how-do-you-log-all-events-fired-by-an-element-in-jquery)

Comment: Hi @andys this feature doesn't seem to work for any of the custom events in the examples, just regular events such as "click", "mouseup", "mousedown", etc...