# Is it possible to listen to all events triggered on an element

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, listener, dom-events

Is it possible to listen to all events that are triggered on a DOM element no matter the name of the event? And if its possible is there any reason one should no do that?

Unfortunately I was not able to find anything about that in either Stack Overflow or Google :(

I am planning to write a script that needs to respond to about two dozens different custom events and I was wondering if, instead of binding each event to the element I could just listen for all of them and then based on the event name, dynamically call a function..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listen to all javascript events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489433/listen-to-all-javascript-events)

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Can you give some context?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: OP said they couldn't find anything! Stop embarrassing them!

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: PS: since its been flagged as a possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489433/listen-to-all-javascript-events): thats not what I am trying to do. The thread in question ask: "Is it possible to listen to all javascript events?"

I want more than listening/printing, I want to execute a function whenever an event triggers...

Comment: I am planning to write a script that needs to respond to about 2 dozens different custom events and I was wondering if, instead of binding each event to the element I could just listen for all of them and then based on the event name, dynamically call a function...

Comment: @Kriesi unfortunately no, you need to declare all the events you're interested in listening.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in the way you've suggested but this is a simple alternative:

```
const events = 'click mouseover mouseout';

events.split(' ').forEach(e => window.addEventListener(e, doStuff));

function doStuff(){...}
```