# detect GET method completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

I have a custom plugin for FireFox which writes a file in the users filesystem at a specified location.  The plugin is invoked via appending a hidden  tag to the body of the document with the plugin commands as attributes in the tag (Save, Remove etc)  This works great however, I want to know when the entire file has completed writing.  I can see the GET request in the browser debugger network tab and can see when it finishes writing the file.  I want to add an event listener to that GET request and fire a call back when complete on Status 200 OK.  I have tried all kinds of methods like adding an ID to the embed tag and using jQuery $("embed").load(function(){ callback }); But I think I am missing a step or something?

Is there a way to listen for a GET request fired when an  tag has been appended to the body of a document? I would love to find a pure javascript solution.  I do have jQuery available if its easier.  or maybe I am missing something pretty easy to do?

ok so to be clear:

```
$("body")append("<embed type='application/x-abc-fileactions' hidden='true' command='save' filename='c:\fileactions\somefile.txt'>");
```

this fires off a GET request once I embed it and downloads somefile.txt file from a vault server.

I would like to have a callback after the entire file somefile.txt can completed writing.

Let me know if that clears it up?

Comment: you can't reasonably know when an embed has finished loading.

Comment: I think I am finding that out.  However, I can see the GET request.  Is there a way to tell when that has finished? It seems hack but is this something I am looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489433/monitor-all-javascript-events-in-the-browser-console

Comment: i'm sorry but you are limited to what the browser can give you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Appreciate the comments...