# Track all custom events on global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have global variable, let's call it `jsEvents` which serves as dispatcher for all events in project. There are about 200 listeners and about the same quantity of custom events, such as

```
$(jsEvents).on('customEvent', function(){
//doing something
})
```

Now I want to investigate what exactly is going on between one event and another event. So I want to log every event at the time it occurs, so I could check if the sequence is correct.

One way is write `console.log` in every event listener, but may be it's possible to listen `any` event? And typeout it's name?

Something like

```
$(jsEvents).on('*', function(){
//here I want to console.log event's name
})
```

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489433/monitor-all-javascript-events-in-the-browser-console

Comment: It doesnt, because I'm using custom events names and it's not DOM element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For debugging you could override dispatch of the jQuery event object. Something like this for example:

```
var temp = $.event.dispatch;

$.event.dispatch = function(event){
    // the event that is passed is the native event, if you want the jquery
    // event, you need the fixed event.
    console.log(jQuery.event.fix( event ));
    temp.call(this, event);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8a530fjx/

Comment: That's the closest match. Something that I also arrived to, modyfiyng `trigger` function in jQuery. I still dont' know what object name the event was called at, but I can filter out DOM events and I can see name of the event.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be done by adding additional data in your custom event and retrieving same in listener

```
    var event = new CustomEvent('build', { 'detail': elem.dataset.time });
    function eventHandler(e) {
    console.log('The time is: ' + e.detail);
    }
```

CustomEvent interface can be used to set details which you can retrieve in listener. For more details please refer to  [CustomEvent Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)

**Eidt:** Unfortunately this requires to provide detail in customEvent, while adding details can be avoided
by using `console.log("Custom event is " event.type);`

```
var event = new CustomEvent('build');
function eventHandler() {
console.log('The event is: ' + event.type);
}
document.addEventListener('build',eventHandler,true);
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: You mean addding additional data in _each and every_ custom event and after that in _each and every_ listener? That's what I don't want to do - even copying will take hours - I don't really want to rewrite the whole code just to debug it. So the question is how to find and listen all custom events without actually rewritng them.

Comment: you didnt mention that you dont want to modify your existing listener, "One way is write console.log in every event listener, but may be it's possible to listen any event? And typeout it's name?" - which means you will be midifying your listener

Comment: _one way_ is to modify every listener and its obvious. And difficult. I'm looking for another way.

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify your event dispatcher. idea is after you done with dispatching an event normally you specially dispatch another event named, say * and in event data pass the actual event name for which it is triggered. than with a single listener registered for * event can help you without modifying your all existing listeners.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a way to get all events bound to one element:

```
function getAllEvents(element) {
    var result = [];
    var events = $._data( element[0], "events" );
    for(e in events){
        result.push(e);
    }
    return result.join(' ');
}
```

Then use that to create a debugger listener:

```
//listener
$('#testElem').on(allEvents, function(e){
    console.log('the event is :', e);
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/qhwfzxzb/

Comment: I dont' use DOM element as dispatcher, so there is no `$._data` property in it. jQuery lets you use `any` global window property as dispatcher. Not just DOM elements.